# Installshield prq target runtime

Tags: installshield

I am building a setup file that requires me to deploy SQL CE 4 using installshield.

What do I need to add to my prq file to only install the required runtime version of sql ce. Currently when I try to run the setup wizard I am getting an error if I try to install the x64 version on a x86 machine and also the same when the machines are reversed.

My files look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SetupPrereq>
<files>
    <file LocalFile="&lt;ISProductFolder&gt;\SetupPrerequisites\SQL CE4\SSCERuntime_x64-ENU.exe" CheckSum="A417082ECAEDD95AFB41F73DC140C350" FileSize="0,2621240"></file>
</files>
<execute file="SSCERuntime_x64-ENU.exe" cmdlinesilent="/q /norestart"></execute>
<properties Id="{F7BF54C1-CA2C-4410-98DB-480769CE6547}" Description="This prerequisite installs the Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4."></properties></SetupPrereq>
```

And

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SetupPrereq>
<files>
<file LocalFile="&lt;ISProductFolder&gt;\SetupPrerequisites\SQL CE 4\SSCERuntime_x86- ENU.exe" CheckSum="0A55733CF406FBD05DFCFF5A27A0B4F7" FileSize="0,2379544"></file> </files>
<execute file="SSCERuntime_x86-ENU.exe" cmdlinesilent="/q /norestart"></execute>
<properties Id="{6BD58ED0-FA9A-44BC-A201-B9D6128459AD}" Description="This prerequisite installs the Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4."></properties>
</SetupPrereq>
```

ANy suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like you've specified any platform or OS conditions on that prerequisite. Try adding those so each prerequisite only runs on the correct system. You may also want to add regular "existence" conditions that ensure the prerequisite is only run when it's not already installed.

Comment: Hi Michael,
How do I do that? I am new to installshield. 
I have created a new condition and I am assuming thats what your talking about. I am just not sure what to do from this point on.